# prove or disprove: $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=0 \implies \lim \frac{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}}\ne 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

my attempt $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}}\text{ yields }\frac{0}{0}$$ then use l'hopital on this

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}} =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{f'}{g}-\frac{fg'}{g^2}}{\frac{f''}{g'}-\frac{f'g''}{g'^2}} $$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}} =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{f'}{f}\frac{f}{g}-\frac{f}{g}\frac{g'}{g}}{\frac{f''}{f'}\frac{f'}{g'}-\frac{f'}{g'}\frac{g''}{g'}} $$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{f}{g}}{\frac{f'}{g'}} =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{f}{g} \left( \frac{f'}{g'}-\frac{f}{g}\right)}{\frac{f'}{g'} \left( \frac{f''}{f'}-\frac{g''}{g'}\right)} $$ assuming such limits exists, and equal to $L$,  leads to

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{f}{g}}{\frac{f'}{g'}} =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{f}{g}  }{\frac{f'}{g'}  }\cdot \lim \frac{  \left( \frac{f'}{g'}-\frac{f}{g}\right)}{ \left( \frac{f''}{f'}-\frac{g''}{g'}\right)} $$

$$L =L\cdot \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{  \left( \frac{f'}{g'}-\frac{f}{g}\right)}{ \left( \frac{f''}{f'}-\frac{g''}{g'}\right)}  $$

I am stuck here..

I would really like to prove that $L$ is not zero and not $\infty$ the proof is  obvious for polynomials functions f, and g, and I can not find any counter examples.. any help would be much appreciated..

we can assume the initial condition comes from appropriately using l'hopital

Comment: some background i attempted to ask it but maybe i did not ask in a proper way.. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761423/lhopital-quicky

Comment: I'm a little concerned that you equate $f'/g$ with $f'/f . f/g$ since $f$ is zero in the limit and possibly around the limit too ?

Comment: thank you @TomCollinge you are correct, I should say: assume f and g are not zero.., so the l'hopital condition was originally met by $$\lim\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\text{ yields }\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$   also assume $f'$, $g'$ not zero... while we are at it..

Comment: If $f$ is infinite then I still think there is still a problem to equate $f′/g$ with $f′/f.f/g$

Comment: that's an excellent point @TomCollinge I am now not so comfortable with that step.. and even if it was ok .. my method seems to be taking me nowhere..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ and $g(x)=e^{-x}$.

Comment: Alternatively: $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = e^{x^2}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I started out with that (look at the edit history), but decided the limit in that case really is *not* equal to $0$ (because it doesn't exist).

Comment: Ah, my mistake.

Comment: thank you Barry this does the trick beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw Barry Cipra had given the same answer...not sure how I could have missed that.

If $f=e^{-x^2}$ and $g=e^{-x}$, you get
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f}{g}
=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f'}{g'}
=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f/f'}{g/g'}
=0
$$
which is a counter-example to your hypothesis.

For the alternative hypothesis ($L=\infty$), you can set $f=e^x$, $g=e^{x^2}$ to get
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f}{g}
=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f'}{g'}
=0,
\quad
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f/f'}{g/g'}
=\infty.
$$

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it would require some type of lemma which described the behavior of the products and quotients of $\ f:f'::f':f''$.  You can factor $\ f'/g'$  out of the expression you stopped at, but are then stuck with a difference quotient with unlike terms.  Without a rigorous lemma which would allow you replace limits of the divisor and dividend with known quantities, it seems unlikely you would be able to simplify further.  I'll post more if I come up with something further.  Interesting post and concept, however.

One differing thought is that it might be necessary to first prove that indeterminate form is never zero, but I think that is a definition and not provable because indeterminate form has logical elements that correspond to defined numbers and ones that are always undefined (i.e., $\ n/0 $).

Regarding some of the answers ... Let statements can disprove the hypothesis, but the question remains as to "why" they do so.  In the above let statements, the reason the hypothesis can be disproved is because you began with the supposition that indeterminate form can be determined not to be zero.

Comment: Thanks @ Alex Ortiz ;O