# Does this convergence test for series hold?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Long ago before I joined math.se, a friend asked [this question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39979/when-does-lhospitals-rule-work-for-series) after he and I had discussed it some. An answer was accepted that is narrow in scope, so I am going to ask a more specific version of the question.

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are

- positive, differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$,
- with $f$ and $g$ either both concave up or both concave down
- $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$, and
- L'Hospital-like conditions: either $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$.

Under these conditions, is it true that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ converges if and only if $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f'(n)}{g'(n)}$ converges?

I'd be happy to tighten the condition

> with $f$ and $g$ either both concave up or both concave down

to

> $f''$ and $g''$ are both always positive or both always negative

necessitating second-differentiablity of the functions.

The accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39979/when-does-lhospitals-rule-work-for-series) shows the result is true under more narrow constraints on $f$ and $g$.

If the result is true, it would establish the convergence of series like $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{e^n}{e^{2n}-1}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{polynomial}(n)}{\operatorname{exponential}(n)}$ with a *little* less effort than other methods I know.

Comment: I mean, those last two can be done by straight comparison test, which is about as basic as it gets.

Comment: @AdamHughes Straight comparison is not straightforward with those, without a touch of cleverness. $\frac{e^n}{e^{2n}-1}$ is _greater_ than $\frac{e^n}{e^{2n}}$, so you'd have to find some other thing to compare with. Limit comparison works, but to a calc student something else might be easier to work with.

Comment: Alex, you can easily compare to

$${e^n\over e^{2n}-{1\over 2}e^{2n}}={2\over e^n}$$

Comment: @AdamHughes That's the "touch of cleverness" I refer to. Experience makes one able to come up with that, but it's not so easy to students still in calculus class.

Comment: I suppose we'll just differ in opinion there. I've taught that to some of my calculus classes before, and they've been able to do it just fine, and it's equally lacking in cleverness IMO because it does the same kind of trick, i.e. making denominator bigger/smaller to get a smaller/bigger fraction.

Comment: @AdamHughes That's a reasonable position. But I'd still say one technique just drops the ${}-1$, while the other involves seeking out something appropriate to replace it with.

Comment: Sorry, must have missed your comment regarding the clarification of the question. With that, my gut feeling is that it will probably suffice, but I haven't yet investigated. Will think about it if I don't forget.